# Cannot see bottom of printer setup screen

Tags: printing, screen

I am new to Ubuntu, but it seems pretty straightforward so far, except for this glitch.

Intel® 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2 graphics on HP Mini 110C running 14.4 LTS.  All other screens work normally so far.  Cannot scroll down or move window far enough to see "accept" button.  Blind tabbing hasn't worked. Tried every available screen resolution and option.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen is simply too small (1024x768).

Configure your printer with a browser.

Open the URL

```
localhost:631
```

Log in with your user name and password and add your printer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The process looked so simple, but rapidly snowballed.  I used terminal to install cups which then needed root installed. The localhost:631 needed a userid and password, but none of mine worked.  I am new to Ubuntu and Linux, but this seems a  labor intensive process and it is easy to go astray and/or lose track of the goal.

Comment: You had to install cups?

Comment: The password is your sudo password and your username is the output of `whoami` in a terminal.